Einstein Chatbot Timeout
I have an Einstein ChatBot with the ability to transfer conversations to a Live Agent. I would like to customize the timeout settings for the chat. Specifically, I want the chat to timeout if the user doesn't type anything for 5 minutes, or if the agent doesn’t respond within 10 minutes.
How can I configure these timeout settings for both user inactivity and agent inactivity?

I'm looking for something similar.
I've a Message-Web with a Einstein Bot, I can't find where to put the configuration.
In the Event Listener there is not a API for that.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-web/guide/event-listeners.html
